# How do I style the Codename One Calendar?

Tags: java, date, codenameone

I'm trying to get the Codename One Calendar to look like this:

[image]

Instead of like this:

[image]

How do I go about doing this?

I looked at the API but there is no direct equivalent for setting the button colors or title colors and couldn't find a way to change the Sun, Mon etc. strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should style `CalendarDay` in the designer to have the look you want: Font, padding etc.

The `CalendarTitle` UIID can be styled with blue to represent the colors.

To do this double click the theme.res and select the "Theme", press "Add" and type in either `CalendarDay` or `CalendarTitle`. Proceed to derive or override as necessary to produce the desired look. See this for more information: https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---create-a-simple-theme.html

To localize the titles define your own localization bundle as explained here:
https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---localizetranslate-my-application-apply-i18nl10n-internationalizationlocalization-to-my-app.html

Use the resource bundle keys: Calendar.Sunday, Calendar.Monday etc...